# Changing controller variable from factory. AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found this pretty method to catch `window.onbeforeunload` event in **angular**. Now I want to open my modal window from it, but I don't know how can I do this.

This is catch method:

```
examinationApp.factory('beforeUnload', function($rootScope, $window) {
    // Events are broadcast outside the Scope Lifecycle
        $window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
            var confirmation = {};
            var event = $rootScope.$broadcast('onBeforeUnload');
            if (event.defaultPrevented) {
                return confirmation.message;
            }
        };

        $window.onunload = function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('onUnload');
        };

        return {};
    })
    .run(function(beforeUnload) {
        // Must invoke the service at least once
    });
    examinationApp.controller("examinationCtrl", ['$scope', '$window', '$http', '$cookieStore', function ($scope, $window, $http, modalDialog) {
        $scope.$on('onBeforeUnload', function (e, confirmation) {
            confirmation.message = confirmation.message = "All data willl be lost.";
            e.preventDefault();
        });
        $scope.$on('onUnload', function (e) {
            console.log('leaving page'); // Use 'Preserve Log' option in Console
        });
```

In my controller I have aa variable `"modalEndShow=false"`. I want to toggle it when the event is watched.

```
examinationApp.controller("examinationCtrl", ['$scope', '$window', '$http', '$cookieStore', function ($scope, $window, $http, modalDialog) {
modalEndShown=false;}]);
```

So how can I do this? Thanks for your attention.

Comment: is `examinationCtrl` controller is loaded on the page? May be the case is listeners are not attached because of controller is loaded

Comment: You want to toggle this when the event is watched? That's not making sense to me. What exactly are you trying to do? Can you put in other words?

Comment: I have modal window in my html its shown when value of variable in conrollers $scope is true.
I want to open my modal when event onbeforeunload is catched

Comment: Oh and are you saying if you execute `$scope.modalEndShown = true` in the `$on` method it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

You can make that modal pop by doing this:

```
$scope.$on('onBeforeUnload', function (e, confirmation) {
    confirmation.message = confirmation.message = "All data willl be lost.";
    e.preventDefault();
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.modalEndShown = true;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want to skip confirmation procedure. When i erase string with "confirmation.message", and confirm. Event doesn't catching.